# Why is $(4x)' \neq 1$?

Tags: derivatives

My book says that $\left(x^r\right)'=rx^{r-1}$ so $\left(4x\right)'=1\cdot 4^{1-1}=4^{0}$, but $a^{0}=1$?

Comment: The $4$ is a multiplier, and remember that differentiation is a linear operation. In other words, for any function,
$$
(4f)' = 4f'
$$
And in this case, $f = x$, $f' = 1$ so $(4x)' = 4$.

Comment: so, $(4x)'=(4\cdot1x^{1-1})=4$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are applying the rule in a weird (and wrong) way.

Comparing $4x$ and $x^r$, you have that $r=1$, and there is an extra factor $4.$ So

$$(4\cdot x)'=4\cdot(1\cdot x^{1-1})=4.$$

Comment: I imagine the deeper error here is not just misapplying the rule but misunderstanding the role of "$x$" as the input to a function being differentiated, rather than a variable that can stand for any number.

Comment: @EricWofsey: yep, but then the constant factor $x$ should remain... :-)

Answer (score 1):

By applying the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), one has
$$
\left[\,f(ax)\,\right]'=a\cdot f'(ax)\color{red}{\ne} f'(ax).
$$